# Katalon Studio: How to handle disappearing validation or success messages?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

There is situation while using Katalon Studio on automating my application.

On a form, Validation message shown with required fields (just like a tool tip) and disappears.
Katalon could not detect this element.
JavaScript is used at front end.

I want to put assert on this element.

Is there a way ? workaround ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below javascript code helped me:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

WebElement field = driver.findElement(By.name("fname"));
Boolean is_valid = (Boolean)jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].checkValidity();", field);
String message = (String)jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].validationMessage;", field);
```

Answer (score 1):

Get xpath of the notify message "//[@class='noty_message']/span" store in a variable and return message to Testcase in

**Custom Keywords**

@Keyword
def successmsg(){

String messageStatus = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@class='noty_message']/span")).getText()

def storemsg = messageStatus
WebUI.delay(5)

'Message'

return storemsg

}

**Testcase**

def Validationmsg = "Successful"

'Assert message'
 String Actualmessage = CustomKeywords.'commonMethod.customSettings.successmsg'()
  WebUI.verifyEqual(Actualmessage, Validationmsg)